# high severity vulnarebilities npx create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, npx, npm-vulnerabilities

I'm getting above mentioned error and it says to address all issues (including breaking changes), run audit fix --force

when i run npm audit command, it gives following details

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-18T17_42_41_740Z-debug-0.log
```

can anyone please help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by running `npm i --package-lock-only` command.

if it throws `` npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead `` error then run `npm i --package-lock-only --location=global`